# Bash Script for Running Command in Root in ADB Shell

Tags: partitioning, bash, scripts, android

I am trying to dump the partitions of Android devices with netcat.  I have created 3 bash scripts for supporting the process.  I have trouble on the second which to dumpt the specific partition through netcat.  On the command line I used to type the following commands:

1. adb shell
2. su
3. (on root) dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | /sdcard/nc -l -p 8888

Based on the commands above, I have tried to make a bash script with detail below:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   adb shell "su
   dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p 8888"
```

But the result is text file with zero size. I have tried to change the quotation mark for identifying the variable, but the result was still the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess `/dev/examiner` it's `nc`'s path in the Ubuntu filesystem? That would explain that

Comment: No. /dev/examiner/nc is the path of nc application on the Android device. I have tried to put the nc file in the sdcard. But the result is still the same.

Comment: Ah, and anyway reading the question better it wouldn't have explained that at all. However I think that the problem is that the command is executed in the unprivileged `adb` shell, and not in the shell spawned by `su`, which leads to the execution of the pipe without root privileges. Try `adb shell "su -c 'dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p 8888'''`

Comment: It works! Thanks heaps mate! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad that it helped :) I'll make an answer out of my comment then, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
adb shell "su
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p 8888"
```

The problem is that this way the pipe is executed in the unprivileged `adb` shell, and not in the root shell spawned by `su`; this leads to the pipe being executed without root privileges and to the 0-lenght file (probably due to the `if` command failing to read a block device without root privileges).

Run the command directly into the root shell spawned by `su` by using `su`'s `-c` option, which allows to run a command directly into the spawned shell:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
adb shell "su -c 'dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p 8888'"
```